# How to compare a TIN and IDW-derived raster DEM quantitatively?

Tags: tin, comparison, inverse-distance-weighted

I'm a student and got the assignment to compare a TIN with a height raster 'quantitatively' and I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I tried subtracting the one from the other but it doesn't seem to be possible without first turning the TIN into a raster, which kind of beats the point of the exercise.

So far I've worked on ArcGIS 10.4 but I also have QGIS and ArcGIS Pro at my disposal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a statistical approach by creating some random (or regular) point sampling set. You then assign the TIN or IDW DEM (Digital Elevation Model) raster values to this point set. You can then use a subtraction between both extracted values pairs and check standard deviation or variance between them. You could also have a try with a Pearson comparison (in Excel for example) to check if the 2 DEM's values are correlated (they should be).

You say "*which kind of beats the point of the exercise.*" I don't agree : in my opinion, it doesn't seem problematic to rasterise the TIN, as long as you use the same step for rasterisation as the other DEM pixel size. They must be aligned. I would be more extreme, because I actually don't see how you can compare a vector set to a raster set without choosing at least a common data format. Either you vectorise you raster, either you rasterise your vector data.

In any case, you first assumption of substracting both is logical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's nice to hear you think rasterizing the TIN is a decent approach. I tried extracting TIN height to point features but I couldn't find a way to do so. Unless you happen to know one, I'll just stick with the rasterizing :)

Comment: Convert a TIN to points ? Seems like rasterisation to me, as creating an regular array of points or of pixel is about the same in my point of view ;)